# Reverse subset of an array

Tags: java

Can someone tell me why I'm only getting the first and last elements in this subset to swap instead of reversing the whole subset like it's supposed to?

```
package academy.learnprogramming;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr1 = {1, 4, 6, 5, 7, 9, 2, -4, 6, 8, 7, 9, 1};
        arr1 = rangeReverse(arr1, 0, 7);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1));
    }

    public static int[] rangeReverse(int[] a, int beg, int end) {
        int[] newArray = new int[(end-beg)+1];
        for(int i = 0; i<=end; i++) {
            newArray[i] = a[i];
        }
        int maxIndex = newArray.length-1;
        int halfLength = newArray.length / 2;
        for(int i = beg; i<a[halfLength]; i++) {
            int temp = newArray[i];
            newArray[i] = newArray[maxIndex - i];
            newArray[maxIndex - i] = temp;
        }
        return newArray;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: There are two major programming errors in both for loops. You need to learn to debug your code. Either add System.err.println statements to your code and write out the value of each variable during every loop iteration to verify that the values are what you expect or step through it with a debugger. I strongly suggest that you learn the latter. It's one of the most important skills you can have.

Comment: You need to change the value of `maxIndex` too - `newArray[maxIndex - i]`